# Find if x is divisible by a number in the sequence from 2 to p

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

What's the best way ( in terms of complexity ) to find if $x$ is divisible by any number between $2..p$ ( inclusive), the obvious solution is to iterate over all numbers $i$ between $2$ and $p$ and check if $x\%i==0$, that's work in $O(p)$.

My solution is to find all divisor of $x$ in $O(\sqrt{x})$ and check if one of these divisors is between $2$ and $p$, is there a faster approach?

Comment: For divisors not too large, lets say upto $30$ digits, ECM is quite efficient. In general, the problem is as hard as integer factorization with unknown complexity. Strictly speaking, ECM never guarantees that there is no prime factor below $10^{30}$, but it can be made very likely that there is none. If the number is small enough, it can be completely factored with the number field sieve.

Comment: @Peter execuse me but what do you mean by ECM, btw x and p are up to 10^9.

Comment: The elliptic curve method (ECM) is an efficient method to find small prime factors. If you download GMP-ECM or yafu, you can easily find factors upto , lets say $20$ digits, even of very large numbers. But if your numbers are so small, this would be an overkill. If p exceeds $\sqrt{x}$, it boils down to a primilaty test which can be done efficiently, but for so small numbers, trial division will not be much slower. So, in your case, trial division is efficiently enough.